# In a text input control, how do I replace delete with backspace and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The requirement is: In a text input control, when the user presses 'delete' key, the default outcome should be prevented (that is possible with e.preventDefault()) and instead the 'backspace' event should be triggered.

In other words: on a text input control, when the user presses delete key in his keyboard, he should see the effect of pressing backspace key in his keyboard.

For example, you have the text "REACT" in the text input control.  With cursor in between 'A' and 'C', you press delete key in your keyboard, it should remove 'A' but not 'C'.

How do we achieve this in Reactjs?

Answer (score 1):

Refer This Code! Delete is replace by Backspace hope this will help you.

```js
        class Todo extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state={
            value:''
          }
        }

        handleChange=(e)=>{
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            value:e.target.value
          })
        }

       
        onDelete= (e)=>{
          if(e.keyCode === 46)
          {
            e.target.setSelectionRange(e.target.selectionStart-1,e.target.selectionStart);
          }

        }

        render(){
          return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <input 
                 value={this.state.value}
                 onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
                 onKeyDown={(e)=>this.onDelete(e)}
                 name = 'txt'
           />
            you type:{this.state.value}
           </React.Fragment>
        )}
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('root'));;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library for keyboard event in react https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keyboard-event-handler.

Like

```
<KeyboardEventHandler
handleKeys={['delete']}
onKeyEvent={(key, e) => /*Your functionality*/}
```

/>

Comment: Thanks Anuj.  Preventing (the delete operation here) is easy but the challenge is to replace it with another (the delete operation to be replaced by backspace). That is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function keyDownEvent(event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if (key == "46") {
            var InputValue = $("#TestInput").val();
            InputValue = InputValue.substr(0, InputValue.length - 1);
            $("#TestInput").val(InputValue);
        }
    }


 <input type="text" id="TestInput" onkeydown="keyDownEvent(event)" />
```

try this code..

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, i think

**React Hooks version**

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function removeAtIndex(str, index) {
    return str.substring(0, index - 1) + str.substring(index);
  }

  function onChange(event) {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Delete" || event.key === "Backspace") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { value: str, selectionStart: i } = event.target;
      const index = event.key === "Delete" ? i : i + 1;
      setValue(removeAtIndex(str, index));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input {...{ onChange, value, onKeyDown }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**React Component version**

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  removeAtIndex = (str, index) => {
    return str.substring(0, index - 1) + str.substring(index);
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.key === "Delete" || event.key === "Backspace") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { value: str, selectionStart: i } = event.target;
      const index = event.key === "Delete" ? i : i + 1;
      this.setState({ value: this.removeAtIndex(str, index) });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.value}
          onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you just update the input value and append a space to it:

```js
const onKeyDown = (e)=>{
 e.preventDefault()
 if(e.key==='Delete')
  e.target.value += " " 
// ...rest
// or update the state(recommended if you have a controlled input)
}
```

Comment: _“you just update the input value and append a space to it”_ - way too naive of an approach; what if my cursor caret wasn’t positioned at the end of the value …?

Comment: I can guess that you want sorted or an event proxy! prevent one and fire the other, but on our craft, we first think of the simplest solution to achieve the goal then we iterate !